# virtual override function not getting called

Tags: c++

The following code when run throws exception instead of printing correctly. I am not able to understand why the virtual override isn't working here ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void print()  const {
        throw runtime_error("");
    }
};

struct Foo : public Base {
    void print() const override {
        cout << "foo" << endl;
    }
};

struct Bar : public Base {
    void print() const override {
        cout << "bar" << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    vector<Base> l = {
        Foo(),
        Bar(),
    };

    for(const auto& x : l) {
        x.print();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want polymorphism your vector should hold references or pointers, not solid objects.

Comment: Try `vector<shared_ptr<Base>> l = { make_shared<Foo>(), make_shared<Bar>() }` with `x->print()`...